# Hyperledger fabric composer- query modelling issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to pass multiple parameters(for example array) using Hyperledger query language.
like -

```
query selectClaimsByMultipleTransanctionID{
  description: "Select all claims based on TransactionID"
  statement:
      SELECT bbc.example.biznet
          WHERE (transactionId **in** _$transactionId)
}
```

But the "In" operator is not available. Can anyone suggest some other way??

Answer (score 1):

Yes - just use `CONTAINS` eg. you can do

SELECT ncb1.example.biznet.Claims WHERE (txnArrayValues CONTAINS ["nnn", "nnn", "nnnn"])

where txnArrayValues is `String txnArrayValues[]` in your model

See Query guide here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/query-language

Answer (score 0):

Using `CONTAINS` operator you can pass multiple parameters.

> for example

Model File:

```
participant User identified by id {
  o String id
  o String[] hobbies
}
```

Query:

```
query Q6 {
    description: "Select all users based on given hobbies"
    statement:
        SELECT ***.User
            WHERE (hobbies CONTAINS ['driving', 'swimming','...']
}
```